# How to route users to separate standalone react apps using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, mern

I have extensively searched the web but could not find a solution, maybe I am wording the problem in an uncommon way.

I am building a Node-Express website that only needs ReactJS on one or two pages. All other pages are server-side rendered.

When a user wants to visit a regular page, I use Express and EJS to render the view. But when the user wants to visit a page that I have built with react, I want the user to see a single-page React Application. When the user wants to visit another page, that I have build with react, the user sees another totally separate single-page react app. Meaning, I don't want to use React-Router across my website. I don't need react for the most part of the website.

I am currently using a React CDN. It works, but the capabilities are limited. I can't npm install ready-made components.

Let's say I want the routes "/" and "/app" to be the two separate react apps, and all other routes to be server rendered. How would I go about that? Would I run create-react-app twice in two separate folders, one for "/" and one for "/app"?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for such kind of scenarios I would make a **subdomain** to separate logic  of the app. for example if my domain is **example.com** which may be a dynamic website, i'd make **admin.example.com** to host my admin dashboard in react or any other single page framework.

Regarding your question, if you're confined to use your approach then firstly your should define a base name in **BrowerRouter** of react-router-dom to host your react app under the url

```
// this way host react app under example.com/calendar
<BrowserRouter basename="/dashboard">
    <Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
    <Link to="/tomorrow"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/tomorrow">
    ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now in your index.html add

```
<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
```

If you need to push to certain url in react app then make a seperate file

```
//history.js
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({ basename: 'dashboard'});
```

Similarly when defining your routes use

```
<!-- import history and add history prop -->
<Router history={history}>
  ...
</Router>
```

Finally in your package.json add homepage path which will be same to basename you defined

```
//package.json
"homepage": "./dashboard"
```

After that you can use typical approach to define routes. If your'e hosting on shared hosting/cpanel, you can paste build folder under the main route foler of the domain. If you're using self-hosted linux servers, you can create different folders and use reverse proxy (apache/nginx) to redirect traffic as you like. I hope this helps.